# How do I check if a environment variable exists in my pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, pom.xml

If someone runs my `pom.xml` they get a nasty error because an environment variable is not defined. I would like to trap this and show a more straightforward error so that the problem can be easily fixed by defined the environment variable. 
I know probably not a good idea to have an environment variable in the pom, but this time I really need to. Any clues?

---

The variable is JAVA_6_HOME, the path to JDK6 since my default one is JDK7

Comment: Can you give more information on what the variable is and why you need it? Someone may be able to find an alternate method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maven-enforcer-plugin can do it:

```xml
<build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>  
              <id>enforce-property</id>
              <goals>
                 <goal>enforce</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                 <rules>
                   <requireEnvironmentVariable>
                      <variableName>JAVA_6_HOME</variableName>
                      <message>JAVA_6_HOME system variable must be set!</message>
                   </requireEnvironmentVariable>
                 </rules>
                 <fail>true</fail>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Great buddy. Do you know how I add a blank line in the error message so it stands out in the maven output?

Comment: Yep. Use separators in your message: <message>${line.separator}JAVA_6_HOME system variable must be set!${line.separator}</message>

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a rule that states a property is required.
Check this SO question [Can I force Maven 2 to require a property to be specified on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425198/can-i-force-maven-2-to-require-a-property-to-be-specified-on-the-command-line)
and this is the link to the maven specification http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html

Here's a link to all the available rules as well:
http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html

Comment: That's awesome Boris. Last question: do you happen to know how I insert blank lines before and after my error message? They are getting lost in the middle of my maven output.