in maven POM or settings file, how can I get something from environment variable or java properties
Suppose I have a settings.xml with some stuff:
<servers>
    <server>
        <username>${env.MAVEN_USERNAME}</username>
    </server>
</servers>

If I wanted to get the username from java properties instead, then I could instead say <username>${MAVEN_USERNAME}</username> (without the env prefix).
So far so good.  What if I want BOTH?  That is, I want to check both and use whichever one is set?  (If both are set I don't care which gets used.)

Would something like this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18162946/4722577

I doubt it?  I don't want to check that it is set... I want to actually use the value!

Actually it seems that <username>${MAVEN_USERNAME}</username> just works... it will indeed read from the environment variable if it exists... now where on earth is this documented??
